# qt base64 encode/decode adds escape characters

Tags: c++, qt, encoding, base64, decoding

I have a method that returns an `unsigned char *` array and I am trying to encode this as base64 and decode it later. So what I am doing is as follows:

```
unsigned char * val = myMethod();
char * encodedMsg = reinterpret_cast<char *>(val);
std::cout << "Returned message: " << val << std::endl;
QByteArray raw = QByteArray(encodedMsg).toBase64(QByteArray::Base64Encoding | QByteArray::OmitTrailingEquals);
```

The output from the method is `\u0001z\ri!i,` and the encoded value is `XHUwMDAxelxyaSFpLA`.

Now, I decode it as follows:

```
QByteArray decoded = QByteArray::fromBase64(raw,
                            QByteArray::Base64Encoding | QByteArray::OmitTrailingEquals);

qDebug() << decoded;
```

Now this returns `\\u0001z\\ri!i,`. Notice that the slashes have been escaped.

I know I can replace this as a post processing step but is there a way to avoid this. Perhaps I am using the encoding/decoding incorrectly?

Comment: I don't see a [mcve] here. What type is `msg->output` and what is `myMethod()`? Why should `cout` and `qDebug()` behave exactly the same?

Comment: I made some edits. `cout` is used there instead of `qDebug()` because the latter does not support `unsigned char *` directly. In any case, QByteArray should honour the binary representation. The question is not about the behaviour of qDebug() vs cout, it is about why the encode and decode does not return the same binary representation back.

Comment: I mean how did you make sure the backslashes aren't added by `qDebug()`? A piece of code one can copy&paste to reproduce your issue locally (IOW, a [mcve]) would be nice...

Comment: I will try to add somethinf  bit more concrete. I verified that ny reading it into a ByteArray again and checking the values. I will make some edits.

Answer (score 1):

Try like below,

Base 64 Encode :

`unsigned char* Ciphertext = Encypt();
       QByteArray qByteArray((char*)(Ciphertext),(int)strlen((char *)Ciphertext));
       qDebug()<<"Ciphertext : "<< qByteArray.toBase64();`

Output :

```
Ciphertext :  "WLdC+ri94z940BiAven6qXQH6rPbE64nQXt5aFByLGPFh1n//tOGLG02zBSoZ79qMA"
```

Base 64 Decode :

```
QString data = QString::fromLatin1(QByteArray::fromBase64(Base64QByteArray.toBase64()).data());
```

in my case i used this base64 conversion for AES encyption, make it shoultable for yours.